# Smallest size of graph covered by infinite tree

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, trees, extremal-graph-theory, covering

Let $T$ be the universal covering tree of some finite, connected, non-tree graph, and let $n_0(T)$ be the smallest positive integer such that there exists a graph $G$ (loops and multiple edges allowed) on $n=n_0(T)$ vertices which is covered by $T$.

If $T$ is the $k$-regular tree for some $k\ge 2$, then it's easy to check that
$$ n_0(T)=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $k$ is even,} \\ 2 & \text{if $k$ is odd.}\end{cases} $$

If $T$ is the $(c,d)$-biregular tree, with $2\le c<d$, then one clearly has $n_0(T)\le c+d$ (because $K_{c,d}$ is covered by $T$). If $(c,d)=1$, then one can also conclude from Sunada's gap labeling theorem, and the fact that $\mu_T(\{0\})=(d-c)/(c+d)$, that $n_0(T)=c+d$. What can we say in the case $(c,d)>1$?

Are there any general results in the literature concerning this quantity $n_0(T)$ (other than immediate consequences of Sunada's gap labeling theorem)?

Comment: I may have problems with the definition of covering, but can't every tree (or even graph) cover a single node with a loop?

Comment: @M.Winter A covering, like here is meant, is a surjection which is also a local bijection, that is which preserve the (local) degree structure.

Comment: Then how can $n_0(T)=1$ for a, say, 4-regular tree?

Comment: @M.Winter Take the graph with one vertex and two loops.

Comment: Then how is this "locally bijective"? Not every edge of the tree is mapped onto a unique loop. And why can't I do the same with a 3-regular tree. My guess: this is what you mean with "degree structure" and you need to map the tree's edges somehow uniformly to the edges of the covered graph? Is this right? I would not call this bijective though. Is this standard?

Comment: @M.Winter Okay, maybe "locally bijective" is misleading when we allow non-simple graphs. For non-simple graphs we need to account for intersection multiplicities. In the example of the single vertex with two loops, the vertex has itself as neighbor with multiplicity four, two for each loop.

Comment: For the 3-regular tree, the smallest graph would have two vertices, linked by an edge, and with a loop at each.

Comment: $n_0(T)\leq (c+d)/(c,d)$, as $K_{c,d}$ covers a graph with $(c+d)/(c,d)$ vertices. I do not know what Sunada's gap labeling theorem is, but I guess that this is optimal.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about results in the literature, but here is a hands-on solution for the $(c,d)$-biregular tree $T$ when $(c,d)$ is arbitrary.

First note that $n_0(T) \leq \frac{c+d}{\gcd(c,d)}$; indeed $T$ covers the graph obtained from $K_{\frac c{\gcd(c,d)},\frac d{\gcd(c,d)}}$ by replacing each edge by $\gcd(c,d)$ many parallel edges.

Now let $G$ be any finite graph covered by $T$. It is not hard to see that $G$ must be bipartite with bipartition $V(G) = A \uplus B$, where each vertex in $A$ is incident to $c$ edges, and each vertex in $B$ is incident to $d$ edges. So $|E| = c \cdot |A| = d \cdot |B|,$
and dividing by $\gcd(c,d)$ we get that
$$\frac c{\gcd(c,d)} \cdot |A| = \frac d {\gcd(c,d)} \cdot |B|.$$
Since $\frac c{\gcd(c,d)}$ and $\frac d {\gcd(c,d)}$ are relatively prime, this implies that $\frac d {\gcd(c,d)}$ divides $|A|$ and consequently $\frac d {\gcd(c,d)} \leq |A|$, and similarly $\frac c {\gcd(c,d)} \leq |B|$. So $|V(G)| = |A|+|B| \geq \frac{c+d}{\gcd(c,d)}$ thus showing that $$n_0(T) = \frac{c+d}{\gcd(c,d)}.$$